# Transforming overdetermined system of equations to normal system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the following overdetermined linear system

$$Ax=b$$

where $A$ is a given tall $n \times k$ matrix ($n>k$), $x$ is a $k$-vector of unknowns, and $b$ is a given $n$-vector. Suppose further that matrix $A$ has full column rank, i.e., $\mbox{rank} (A)=k$. Is it legitimate to delete linearly dependent rows?

If so, then we obtain another system of linear equations which has the same number of equations as the number of unknowns. Hence, the conclusion is that any overdetermined system of linear equations can be transformed to one where the number of equations is equal to the number of unknowns. Where is the problem in my reasoning? Please guide me!

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is fine as long as your system is consistent (i.e. has a solution). There is just one thing to consider: Some people also write *inconsistent* overdetermined systems that way - that are systems that have no solution. This might result in different solutions depending on which rows you remove.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just for clarification, does your answer imply that any consistent and overdetermined system of linear equations (SLE) has the identical alternative form where numberof equations are eqaul to number of unknowns?

Comment: Yes that is right!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example $(n=3,\,k=2)$
$$\eqalign{
A=\pmatrix{1&4\\2&5\\2&6},\quad b=\pmatrix{12\\13\\14},\quad{\rm rank}(A)=2 \\
}$$
Technically, any of the three rows of $A$ is a linear combination of other two.

For example, you can write the third row as 
$$\eqalign{
\pmatrix{2&6} = \tfrac{2}{3}\pmatrix{1&4} + \tfrac{2}{3}\pmatrix{2&5}
}$$
The concept of *linear dependence* isn't enough, because it doesn't tell you which row to eliminate.

Eliminating the first, second, or third row will yield three completely different answers 
$$\eqalign{
x_1 &= \pmatrix{4\\1}
, \quad
x_2 &= \pmatrix{-8\\\;\;5}
, \quad
x_3 &= \pmatrix{-8/3\\\;11/3} 
}$$
What you should really do in this situation is calculate the *least-squares* solution using all of the rows.
$$\eqalign{
x_L &= \pmatrix{-40/17\\\;\;57/17} 
}$$

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Do you mean that eliminating rows is incorrect? I don't understand why one should approximate solutions instead of analytical one?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is a *consistent* or *inconsistent* system of equations, if you want to use analytical methods, you can delete any *dependent* row which you can establish to be a valid *linear combination* of any subset of the other *undeleted* rows. However you must also join the left hand side values as a column of your matrix with value: **-b**. Otherwise you will struggle with inconsistent results in your calculation. The negation of that column is essential.

**Special Note:** make sure you do your row deletions, only one row at a time. If you delete more than one row at a time, you will inadvertently delete a *linearly essential* row. Guassian reduction remains the best way to identify such rows even when N > M. It also exposes the row which will never combine with any set of the rest, or the cause of the *inconsistency*, if the system is inconsistent.